# Why does DialogContent add a scroll bar insead of just spreading further when it includes nested Grids with spacing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I currently work on a form which is displayed in a dialog window. In order to adjust the layout of form's fields I use a couple of `Grid`s inside of another `Grid`. I've discovered that when a `Grid` with any `spacing` is the last subcomponent of the main `Grid` there is a scroll bar added even though there is plenty of space where the entire dialog could stretch:
[image]

I've managed to reproduce it in [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-fi7yv?file=/demo.js).
When anything else is the last subcomponent of the `DialogContent` everything is fine. Even a simple `<p/>` fixes it. When main `Grid` doesn't have `spacing` parameter it's also fine.

This weird glitch took much of my time so I'd really like to know why this happens (in order to possibly avoid similar glitches in the future).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That may be related to [negative margin](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/#negative-margin).

Excerpted workarounds are:

> 1. Not using the spacing feature and implementing it in user space spacing={0}(default).
> 2. Applying padding to the parent with at least half the spacing value applied to the child:
> 3. Adding overflow-x: hidden; to the parent.